# How to show the distance using geolocation?

Tags: magento2.3.2, google-map, locations

I have an address (with lan,lon) and want to show the distance from current location to that address using geolocation.

How can i achieve that?

Can anyone please guide me?

Comment: Please specify what you have tried and which Magento version, you have tried?

Comment: You can create custom module using above document
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/distance-matrix

Comment: @AmitBera, I want to show the distance from user current location to pickup address in Product details page under product name. Magento version 2.3.2

Comment: @Soundararajanm, How to show the current location in it?